# jQuery+JavaScript: Create custom ajax call function with single object as argument

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I need code example for:

- custom JavaScript function that takes a **single object** as an argument
- uses jquery ajax method to make ajax call
- object argument should specify all possible values that can be customized.
- For example: type of ajax call, data to be passed, success, error handlers etc. etc.
- if any values are not present it should assume defaults

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: www.google.com is your friend here, its more of a wish list than a question

Comment: I looked up on google and stackoverflow but did not find anything similar. Idea is to have a custom function which takes an object as an argument and makes ajax call based on that.

Comment: its discouraging that people are putting the effort to put the question down instead of helping out (which I believe is the purpose of this community).

Comment: Because this is not a question, it is a request for us to do the work for you. Why not try something and if you get stuck as us for help.

Comment: @locrizak the intention was not to make you or anyone else do my work... If that was the case I'd post details of my entire project. I came across a problem... did not find the solution I was looking for so I posted it here because 1. yes I'm looking for a solution and 2. if others came across the same issue they can find the solution too

Comment: @Adi: The issue people are having with this question is that you didn't try to solve this yourself.  Take a look at the jQuery docs for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and try to solve this yourself.  Post a question if you get stuck somewhere along the way.

Comment: @Rocket thanks for helping out and your point it taken.. will make sure to post code examples with my question from next time on. Would have preferred some level of support from people (e.g. point to a resource) rather then full-on bashing :) Just does not help when you're trying really hard to learn something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic skeleton of the function you are trying to make.

```
function AJAXCall(obj){
  var type = obj.type || 'GET'; // 'GET' is the default here
  // more variables...
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    type: type,
    // more options...
  });
}
```

Then you can call your function like so:

```
var options = {
  type: 'POST'
  // more options...
};
AJAXCall(options);
```

Here are the docs for `$.ajax`, they may help: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/